# How to prove that identical particles are attracted or repelled in a given spin-s interaction theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, scattering, interactions

Let's assume that we have integer spin interaction theory (EM field, linearized gravity, arbitrary gauge spin s theory). How to prove the consequence that in interaction theory with spin $s = 2n$ two identical particles (equal spins, masses, all charges etc) are attracted (like gravity), while in $s = 2n + 1$ theory they are repelled (like in EM interactions)?

Comment: Maybe you will be intereted by this short [answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/72139/6316), although some interesting precisions should be added..

Comment: @Trimok : thank you for the answer and for the reference. But can be earned the general result from my question?

Comment: The general idea, is that, for a field with a spin $s$ interaction, you have, in the Lagrangian, a time derivative term of spatial components which is (roughly) $\partial_0 A^{{i_1 i_2 ...i_s}} \partial^0 A_{{i_1 i_2 ...i_s}}$. We want to have a positive quantity, which is $(\partial_0 A^{{i_1 i_2 ...i_s}})^2$. To go from the first expression to the last expression, you have a factor $g^{00} g^{i_1 i_1} g^{i_2 i_2}...g^{i_s i_s}$, which is equal to $(-1)^s$.