# What carries the electrostatic and magnetostatic forces?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, magnetostatics

In the Standard Model of QM, all forces are mediated or carried by particles (for want of a better word) called bosons. The photon is an example of a force-carrying gauge boson, and mediates the electromagnetic force.

The electrostatic and magnetostatic forces are not mediated by real photons, and [the answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/196774/how-is-the-em-force-exchanged-over-long-distances) explains that they are not mediated by virtual photons either, while [the answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142159/deriving-the-coulomb-force-equation-from-the-idea-of-photon-exchange) goes way over my head.

Put simply, what particles are these forces carried by - or aren't they after all?

As an example, consider a charged fragment of paper levitated above a charged metal plate. Nothing appears to be moving or changing its momentum or anything; no work is being done, no energy is going anywhere. The electrostatic levitating force is counterbalanced not by another electromagnetic force but by gravity. How does that work, then?

Comment: The answer you last cited is actually also over my head. But I think it sounds pretty correct if I say: static fields do not exist in nature. Anytime a charge is accelerated in the apparently static field of another charge, this acceleration violates the assumption of "static-ness" because it means that (classically) EM waves get radiated by the mutually accelerated charges. In the quantum field theoretical description these actual waves correspond to real photons.

Comment: Then, if you go to the limit of infinitely slow processes, the exchanged photons make up the changes in the static fields, but never the static fields themselves because these are artifacts of the classical description. At least this is what I read out of the cited answer.

Comment: @oliver I ask about forces, not fields. A static field can still exert a force, even when nothing is moving/changing. One of the answers I link to states that virtual photons are a mistaken concept.

Comment: I don't know what your point is. If a charge experiences no acceleration, the electromagnetic field must be zero where it's located. Nothing magical there that would invalidate the general field concept. The superposition of two static fields to obtain a zero field strength at some location is an artificial construction that serves as an excuse for not knowing the underlying physics (i.e. QFT).

Comment: @oliver No. Consider a levitating magnet. The magnetic force is opposed by gravity, not by some other electromagnetic force. You cannot just use sophistry to explain the problem away like that.

Comment: I think the first answer of mine that you linked would be almost verbatim what I'd also write here as an answer - can you be a bit more specific what you think is lacking? Perhaps the problem is the word "mediating" - I think the answers you linked explain the specific sense in which the EM force is "mediated by" photons. Is your problem that this doesn't fit with a more colloquial or intuitive meaning of the word?

Comment: @ACuriousMind "Mediating" simply means carrying, as in force-carriers, in the sense that when a force is exerted it is via "particles" (field perturbations) passing between the objects concerned. You note that "*nothing detectable, as far as we know, is actually 'exchanged'*", in which case how is the (sometimes very substantial) force exerted?

Comment: There is no notion of "exertion of force" in quantum mechanics. A force as something that is "exerted" is a rather classical concept. You're looking for something that doesn't exist. The meaning of "force" in the context of ["four fundamental forces"](https://xkcd.com/1489/) is not the same as the meaning of "force" in Newton's laws.

Comment: I think you would be closer to what you mean if you said that there is no notion of "exertion of" force in QM. Yet there is presumably a parallel theory to explain why f=ma for massive quanta, and where say a levitating f comes from if there is no a. Momentum exchanges appear to explain the former but not the latter. What is missing from this picture?

Comment: Quanta are amounts of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charges that are being exchanged between systems. It doesn't matter whether they are "massive" or not. The semi-classical "particle" model is simply not very good. It gives people all the wrong ideas and almost none of the right ones about what nature actually does.

Answer (score 3):

I have never liked the "virtual particles" concept; they're the result of taking Feynman diagrams a tad bit too literally. Feynman diagrams are nice little pictorial representations of terms in a perturbation series designed to calculate scattering elements between two particles; there's one in anna v's answer. However, these should not be taken as literal pictures of what is going on.

Scattering in quantum mechanics is due to interactions between fields. Two particles (which are derivative from a field, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/163705/115161)) in approximate momentum states interact for some finite time and then asymptotically go to some other particle states in the far future (where interactions become negligible). This process is encoded in the LSZ reduction formula, and is our current understanding of how things go about; fields interact with each other. For example, the electron field might interact with the photon field, and this produces scattering.

In the non-relativistic limit, when scattering is not very large, we can neglect all but the leading order term in the perturbation series (encoded in the diagram in anna v's answer). Now, because we are in the non-relativistic limit, we can assume the Bohr approximation from regular QM holds. Thus, we can pretend the scattering is actually due to some potential, which comes out to be the Coulomb potential. However, in the end, it is (to the best of our knowledge) just fields interacting with other fields.

Comment: Fields interacting with other fields seems to be a very Classical model. Are you saying that QFT is, in this respect, a Classical field theory? Also, anna v talks of changing momentum vectors, yet a static field is just that, static. So this does not make clear to me how the quantum aspect explains the force exerted.

Comment: @GuyInchbald this answer is quite correct. Fields interact with fields, whether you are talking about classical or quantum field theory. That's the entire point. The only sense in which particles are even defined is via Wigner's classification theorem for the Poincare group. Everything else if just fields doing things, and it happens that if in certain asymptotic limits the theory is free (which is what LSZ gets at) then the fields themselves can be given an interpretation in terms of "particles," so interaction of the fields is tantamount to interaction of the particles.

Comment: @RichardMyers You appear to have jumped to the mistaken conclusion that I am confused over particles vs fields. I understand all that perfectly well, thank you. Please re-read and address what I ask more carefully. Some context for the term "force" would be rather more helpful;  In particular, if a force necessarily involves an exchange of momentum vectors, as anna v stated, then how does that explain a static situation where a force is exerted but movement is restrained?

Comment: @GuyInchbald Force is not a useful concept unless you're building a bridge or rolling a ball on an incline. Use of the word in modern parlance is nothing more than a historical holdover used to talk about gauge theory. Hence, my comment about the accuracy of this answer remains. By the way, your question seems quite preoccupied by "particles," so perhaps you should reread it yourself.

Comment: @RichardMyers That's rubbish. Force *is* a useful concept if one is levitating a scrap of paper or a magnet. Your explanation of how that happens remains conspicuous by its absence. Modern physicists universally refer to the "four fundamental forces" and to gauge bosons as "particles". Just as they and I do, you should understand those words in the context of modern field theory. Hence my question's qualification of "particle (for want of a better word)" - you seem to have missed that bit.

Comment: @GuyInchbald Mr. Myers statement still holds; that's a classical situation, where it makes sense to discuss "force." There are, in reality, four fundamental _interactions_, not forces. These interaction fields allow for, well, interactions between quantum fields. In the proper classical limit, some of these interactions (like electromagnetism) can be interpreted as classical fields imposing classical forces on macroscopic objects, but at the fundamental level, it is, to the best of our knowledge, just fields interacting with one another through these interaction fields.

Comment: There is no "$F=ma$" in quantum mechanics or field theory. This is a classical model, and a good approximation for some macroscopic situations at low velocities, but doesn't hold down here. For your levitating magnet bit, we have some field mediating interactions between matter fields, which classically looks like an electrostatic field exerting a force on the paper. This is not what is actually happening! That is a classical approximation, but is not reality; the reality is fields interacting with fields (AFAWK). Gravity is the result of another field, which classically pulls the scrap down.

Comment: @JohnDumancic I think the problem with these "QFT works like this" rabbit-hole explanations is that they just restate one side of the problem, they do not actually answer it. They seem obsessed with debunking the terminology commonly used by mainstream physicists and not with addressing what those physicists actually mean. My question seems simple enough; granted that a "particle" is a field perturbation and a "force" is a mirage, what special properties do the electrostatic and magnetostatic field perturbations display when no energy is transferred? But thanks for trying.

Comment: @GuyInchbald As a general note, particles are not "excitations/perturbations in a field"; this is a [heuristic picture](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/163705/115161). Your question was "Put simply, what particles are these forces carried by - or aren't they after all?" The answer involves no particles and no forces; rather, the photon field mediates interactions between matter fields. In the proper classical limit, this goes to classical electrodynamics.

Comment: @JohnDumancic When is a mode expansion of a field not an excitation/perturbation of that field? Discuss, with reference to interactions in which no energy is transferred.

Answer (score 0):

At the quantum framework, everything in the world is made up by the particles in the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)  and their interactions. All other theories can be shown mathematically to be emergent from this level.

The macroscopic electric and magnetic fields are the result of the addition of a high number of charged quantum particles, what is a "force" at the quantum level is built up to "force" of classical level electric and magnetic fields.

What is the electric "force" at the quantum level? It is the exchange of dp/dt, (p a momentum  vector) between two interacting charged particles, for [example two electrons](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html), a first order term in the expansion in series for the solution :

[image: e-e-]

The diagram is a recipe for writing the integrals necessary for a calculation of the probability of interaction between two electrons.

The dp/dt is assigned to the virtual photon connecting the two vertices. Virtual particles are a mnemonic to help in conserving the quantum numbers characterising the  interaction.

In principle, no matter how far away are two electrons , they will be interacting with such a virtual photon. In order to detect an electric field there **must** be an interaction at the quantum level. When distances are large, the classical "force" can be defined within classical electrodynamics.

So in a nonmathematical  description one can say that a static field is built up by virtual photons. A test charge measuring classically the static electric field reacts with F=ma , and F is the sum of the dp/dt for each individual quantum interaction . Considering that the number of fundamental charges are of the order of ~ $10^{23}$ (avogadro number) it is better to use classical electrodynamics.

Comment: If charged particles in a static field are exchanging momentum vectors, why are they not changing their velocities (e.g. protons in a solid lattice)? Are you saying that the answer I link to, denying virtual photons, is in fact wrong? Can you be explicit about that? How can F=ma occur with, say, a pair of magnets nailed to the wall?

Comment: If a force can be measured, there exists a dp/dt. which is acceleration and is part of the definition of a force. Momentum is exchanged and contrary forces ( of the latice creating the fields) hold everything in place because the individual electron atom interactions at macroscopic distances are very very very very weak. It is the summation that builds up the classical force. Virtual particles are just a mathematical tool, to remember the quantum numbers that must be exchanged between real particles. Real partilcles have their four momentum  on their mass shell, i.e. the "length of the four

Comment: momentum vector is the mass of the real particle. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html  ( special relativity). Real particles are the incoming and outgoing in the diagram.

Comment: Sorry, you seem to be repeating your position and not answering the concerns I raised about it.

Comment: "why are they not changing their velocities (e.g. protons in a solid lattice)?" the change is velocity is what is seen as a macroscopic force, they are changing their velocity is what I am saying, collectively.. (When a ball bounces off a wall how is momentum conserved? by the earth  and the mass of the earth is so huge that no recoil of the wall is seen. ) The force  between the magnets is the collective /summed quantum mechanical interactions between charge and magnetic moments

Comment: "denying virtual photons, is in fact wrong?"  **virtual photons are a mathamatical tool**,  so a tool cannot be denied . That it represents a *measurable* four vector is what is denied,as the mass of the transfer vector is variable and not on mass shell, in the photon  case it is different than zero..

Comment: What is the logical connection between the bouncing of a ball and fixed magnets? Your reasoning has lost me there: either the things are moving or they are not. Then again, saying that virtual photons are a mere artefact of the maths is denying their virtual existence in any physical sense, which is exactly what the answer linked to was saying. Sorry again, but there is no clarity in your clarifications.

Comment: the bouncing ball is an example of the complexity on  conservation of momentum is collective when there are a large number of particles involved (as the earth mass)  it is an analogy, that is why I put it in parenthesis.. The physical existence of a virtual particle is on the paper it is written/dravn. What measurable real value  exists is the transfer of dp/dt, and quantum numbers,.  in the case the virtual partilcle is an electron ,charge and lepton number, Compton scattering for example https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHb6i.png

Comment: Sorry again. Neither the bouncing of a ball nor the existence of a squiggle on a piece of paper has the slightest relevance to a pair of magnets nailed to the wall.