# Are space and matter interchangeable?

Tags: space, casimir-effect

In this post I am referencing the following 'Sixty Symbols' video: [Casimir Effect & Black Holes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRcmqZkGOK4)

The video mentions that the Casimir effect can be used to prove that virtual particles are created from the space vacuum ([2:15 - 4:55](https://youtu.be/IRcmqZkGOK4?t=135)). Under certain circumstances, some of these virtual particles can be turned into real particles, seemingly when a particle and its antiparticle are separated ([4:57 - 7:19](https://youtu.be/IRcmqZkGOK4?t=297)).

Is this enough evidence that space and matter are fundamentally the same and therefore are interchangeable? Can space be converted into matter (and vice versa)?

Comment: Under what circumstances virtual particles can be converted into real ones? Virtual particles are mathematical artifacts of quantum field theory.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Sorry I believe I am misinterpreting this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRcmqZkGOK4. Rather than the Casimir effect describing virtual particles, the Casimir effect is used as proof for virtual particles. Two plates close to each other in a vacuum are pushed together.

Comment: There's a lot to say about this video but unfortunately, this is not the place to talk about it. You must know that what is said in this video is a simplification of the phenomenon described.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Ok, I just read from [this article here](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/) that virtual particles are merely disturbances in the electromagnetic field (photon field) caused by real particles. They should not be thought of as real particles.

Comment: It is unclear what "space and matter are fundamentally the same" actually is supposed to *mean*. We commonly think of matter as existing *within* space.  As for "virtual partlcles" and the vacuum, see e.g https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146003/50583 and its linked questions

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/275099/123208

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of significant downvotes, it is important that we at least consider the possibility of new ideas and new physical models if we wish for science to move forward.  There is a model named Scale Metrics in which space and bound mass (which can be thought of as tiny singularities) couple to form matter.  In this model all matter is derived, in part, from space. If interested, I will let you research this on your own (or at least ask for more information); however, do realize that this is a new idea that has not been heavily reviewed.