Do the quarks in neutrons tend to have much larger momenta than the quarks in protons?
Context
The Feynman diagram for beta decay of a neutron into a proton, electron, and electron antineutrino via an intermediate
$W^-$  boson is given in many places, which includes [1]. I understand that in beta decay the weak force changes the flavour of a single quark.:
$$
d\rightarrow u + W^-\tag{1}$$
By looking at the well-known graphic [2], which give the masses of the particles of the standard model, one observes that the mass of $W^-$ is about 10,000 times larger than the mass of the either the up or down quarks.
I understand that the masses of the reagents and products need not be equal. Yet, In Feynam diagrams, at each vertex there is 4-momentum conservation [3]. Thus, the vertex given in beta decay must have conservation of 4-momentum.
Q.1)
Do the quarks in neutrons tend to have much larger momenta than the quarks in protons?
Q.2)
Can we compute the probability that quarks in neutrons have sufficient momentum to undergo beta decay?
Q.3)
Otherwise, how can one understand the ability of the reaction in Eq. 1 to take place?
Bibliography
[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_and_Z_bosons
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model
[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram

Can you make your point a bit better than a garland of non-sequiturs? You do understand all lines in your diagrams and sub diagrams are virtual, so they need not be on-mass-shell, and there is an indefinite number of exchanged gluons omitted for relevance clarity. Quarks may carry as much as almost 100% of the energy and momentum of a hadron, with a certain probability. What's your point?

what about $W^+ + d \rightarrow u$?

Some useful info on virtual particles: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/700019/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/275099/123208

Some useful info on virtual particles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle#Properties

Your initial premise is wrong because:
$$ d\rightarrow u + W^-\tag{1} $$
does not show the decay of a down quark. The Feynman diagram that you are thinking of:

does not show an actual physical process. It is a graphical representation of a calculation that gives the first term of an infinite sum used to calculate the decay probability. There is no $W^-$ boson present.
With a reaction like beta decay we know the initial state, i.e. a down quark, and we know the final state, i.e. an up quark, electron and antineutrino. However we cannot directly calculate the state of the system in between. Instead we approximate it using an infinite series, of which each term is represented by a Feynman diagram. The picture above shows the first term in this series - the tree level diagram. The $W^-$ in this diagram is a virtual particle that need not and generally does not have the same mass, energy and momentum as a real $W^-$.

Nothing in my comment should be taken as detracting from what John Rennie writes. Rennie's answer is clear. There is an epistemological/pedagogical issue. For example, in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay we find that, "At the fundamental level, this [decay] is caused by the conversion of the negatively charged (−⁠1/3⁠ e) down quark to the positively charged (+⁠2/3⁠ e) up quark by emission of a $W^−$ boson; the $W^-$ boson subsequently decays into an electron and an electron antineutrino." As per Rennie, this quoted description captures only the first term of infinite number of terms.

@MichaelLevy this is a very common misconception and you aren't the first or last to fall into this trap. As you've found even the authors of the Wikipedia article make this misleading statement.

Now in the OFTP formulation, I've also seen a $W^+, e^-, \bar\nu_e$ 'spawn' (sorry) and then the W convert the $d$ quark, so in Feynman diagram form, it's better to say a $W$ is exchanged, with no direction assigned, which is certainly the case in CC neutrino scattering ($\nu n \rightarrow ep$).

My understanding of Breit-Wigner distributions means real $W$'s can have a mass of 5 MeV, it's just the amplitude is tiny..that's the whole meaning of a particle having a "width".

@JEB: OFTP := What exactly?  CC := What exactly?  I like your point of saying $W$ is exchanged. Question: Can you be more precise? Precisely what are what are changing the $W$?

@MichaelLevy Old Fashioned Perturbation Theory, where not-Feynman diagrams are time-ordered and don't conserve energy at the vertex. CC = Charged Current (W exchange). In a t-channel tree diagram the exchange particle doesn't have a direction, so you can't assign a charge to it.
