# Screening of the electric field in the Higgs phase

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electric-fields, quantum-electrodynamics, higgs

Dvali states in his paper on [Three-Form Gauging of axion Symmetries and Gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0507215) that

> “As usual, in the Higgs phase the electric field is completely
>   screened in the vacuum,”

and in another occasion in the same paper that

> “There is a well known way to get rid of any constant electric field
>   in the vacuum (i.e. to screen it), which is by putting the gauge
>   theory in the Higgs phase.”

It may sure be well-known among others, but I for one, am not aware of it. Can someone explain to me with an illustrative example (QED) how this works?

Thanks.

Comment: @DanYand Ah yes, that makes sense. Can you please provide a link (or write an answer) where I can see a comprehensive derivation of the exponential decay of the electric fields due to the gauge bosons becoming massive? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Dan Yand](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/206691/dan-yand) says in a comment, the reason the electric field is "screened" in the Higgs phase is because the Higgs mechanism endows the photon(s) with mass, and massive bosons mediate forces whose classical potential is a [Yukawa potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential) proportional to $\mathrm{e}^{-mr}\frac{1}{r}$, i.e. it is the potential for the massless boson damped by the mass of the boson as the damping (or "screening") factor.

That massive bosons mediate such exponentially damped forces is completely general. I explain the logic of obtaining the classical potential from the quantum field theory in [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/142172/50583), where the tree-level scattering between charged particles essentially tells us the potential is the Fourier transform of the propagator. The Fourier transform of 
$$ \frac{e^2}{q^2 + m^2 - \mathrm{i}\epsilon}$$ 
in 3 dimensions and after $\epsilon\to 0$ is precisely the Yukawa potential:

Carrying out the angular integrations in the 3d integral, one arrives at (modulo factors of $\pi$)
$$ V(r) = \frac{e^2}{\mathrm{i}r}\int \left(\frac{q\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}qr}}{(q+m +\sqrt{\mathrm{i}\epsilon})(q+m -\sqrt{\mathrm{i}\epsilon})}\right)\mathrm{d}q,$$
which is now interpreted as a complex contour integral in the upper half-plane with the contour being the $x$-axis and a half-circle "pushed out to infinity" (to do this properly, you should really take a finite contour and then take a limit, but whatever). The integrand vanishes on the half-circle at infinity, so only the real axis contributes and this is indeed still the same integral. Now we apply the residue theorem - there is a singularity enclosed by the contour at $q_0 = m + \sqrt{\mathrm{i}\epsilon}$ and it is a *simple pole*, i.e. has multiplicity one.

We apply a [standard result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles) about the residues of simple poles that says that $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$ has a residuum of $\mathrm{Res}(f,z_0) = \frac{g(z_0)}{h'(z_0)}$ at a simple pole $z_0$, and obtain that
$$ V(r) = \frac{e^2}{\mathrm{i}r}2\pi\mathrm{i}\frac{m + \sqrt{i\epsilon}}{2(m + \sqrt{i\epsilon})}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(m + \sqrt{\mathrm{i}\epsilon})r}$$
Taking the limit $\epsilon\to 0$ now yields the Yukawa potential as claimed.