# Reason for repulsion of like charges

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, charge

Like charges repel and unlike attract. Like magnetic poles repel and unlike attract. Since electricity and magnetism are fundamentally linked , is this attraction/repulsion due to the magnetic fields and electric fields linked. Is this interaction force a characteristic of the magnetic force or that of the electric force ?

Comment: Neither. That's why it's called electromagnetism. It's the same for both forces.

Comment: Keep in mind that electric charges are not completely analogous to magnetic poles

Comment: I'd say there is no *reason* for this, this is just how the Nature works. You can write the Coulomb's equation that will show you that same charges repel, but it's roundabout: the reason why the equation exist is that it captures the *observed fact* that like charges repel. You can go into more fundamental theories and e. g. [derive Coulomb's law from QED](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/142172/115253), but this won't give you a *reason* either: QED is a more refined theory to *describe what we see*, and what we see is the suckers repel, and that's where it begins, not ends!