# Quantum mechanical explanation of electrostatic force

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, coulombs-law, virtual-particles, carrier-particles

Feynman diagram explains repulsion of electrons by means of photon exchange. Similarly can we explain repulsion of protons and attractions between protons and electrons?

Comment: Is there a reason you would think that we cannot do this?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142159/2451 and links therein.