# Quantum field theory of electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, quantum-electrodynamics, coulombs-law, virtual-particles, carrier-particles

I don't understand how anything in electrostatics, including electric potential and magnetic fields, is possible via the exchange of particles. Since particles are essentially fluctuations in these fields, in the static situation there are not particles, then how can there be force?  Is electrostatics just an illusion?

Comment: This might be an example of where interpreting internal lines in Feynman diagrams too literally might be causing more problems than it solves.

Comment: Electrostatics doesn't need to be explained by the exchange of particles. (That's only how lots of bad sources say it works. As in any other subject that is both technically difficult and popular, bad sources are easier to find than good ones.) In quantum field theory, the electromagnetic field is *still a field*, albeit a quantum one. Quantum fields are not made of particles. Particles are one of the many possible manifestations of a quantum field, but most of a quantum field's manifestations are nothing like particles.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142159/2451 and links therein.

Comment: It is widely overlooked that "electrostatics" is actually not even a solution of classical electromagnetism. There is no static configuration of charges that is stable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem. It should therefor not be surprising that quantum electrodynamics will also not make such a prediction easily. The only way to make "quasi-static" fields is to make a stable configuration of matter, first.

Comment: I gave a good answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/758914/electrostatics-as-the-infrared-limit-of-a-sea-of-photons/758989  However, my answer got promptly down-voted by a physics crank and his sock-puppet. I'm not sure if I should file a complaint or just ignore the abuse.