# Deriving Coulombs law from QED - why must the particles be distinguishable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, coulombs-law

It is possible to derive Coulomb's potential from QED by considering the scattering process $e^-+e^-\rightarrow e^-+e^-$. The argument can be found in Peskin and Schroeder p.125, and it is reproduced in [this stackexchange answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/142172/219131). The authors state that it is necessary to assume that the particles are distinguishable, meaning that only the $t$-channel diagram is included, and not the $u$-channel diagram. Why is this the case? Indistinguishability is of course not unique to QFT (i.e. it is a QM effect also) so I don't understand why it would be ignored in this limit. I expect that it has something to do with the fact that one electron is treated as fixed, but I don't quite follow how.

Comment: Remark: if we do this derivation for different (=distinguishable) particles(e.g., an electron and a proton), the question does not arise. If we were to account for electrons being indistingushable, the Coulomb interaction between distinguishable particles would be different from that for the indistiguishable ones.

Comment: Good point! I suppose this then begs the question: why do distinguishable and indistinguishable particles experience the Coulomb interaction in the same way?

Comment: I would say that they experience Coulomb interaction differently, because they are exchangeable. Mathematically the problem is clear: we put the same Coulomb interaction in the Hamiltonian, but for indistinguishable particles we get extra *exchange* diagrams. So when we work backwards, we ignore these diagrams to get the *correct* answer. But I cannot give a deeper *physical* explanation.

Comment: That is very post-hoc though and is certainly not a *prediction* of QED.

Comment: My background is in solid state - that is I am well familiar with the non-relativistic version of this problem. This is why I am not sure, whether Coulomb potential should be derivable from the scattering cross-section or the other quantity that one calculates. For me what you are trying to do is deconvolving two unrelated effects that contribute to the final result: Coulomb interaction has to do with charge, while exchange has to do with the indistinguishibility.

Comment: I see what you mean. In that case, surely including both diagrams should lead to a potential that includes the effect of the exchange interaction?

Comment: In principle, yes. However, it is not quite clear how to write it mathematiclaly... I could think of electron-hole interaction in semiconductors: holes are just valence electrons with renamed operators, $h_k^\dagger =v_{-}k,h_k=v_{-k}^\dagger$. It might be that the potential is derived somewhere in the books on the theory of excitons. [Knox's book](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Theory_of_Excitons.html?id=GuQ9AQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) could be a place to look at.