# If the exchange of virtual Gravitons isn't real why do bodies attract?

Tags: gravity, quantum-gravity, virtual-particles, carrier-particles

I have been told Earth is **not really** sending particles to me and keeping me on the ground. That it is just a convenient thing to do in calculations.

However if the exchange of gravitons isn't real, then why do bodies attract?

Comment: For the analogous question with virtual photons in QED, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142159/2451) Phys.SE post and links therein.

Comment: Cart before the horse:  we observed that bodies attract and devised the theory of gravitation  in order to model mathematically the observations, and hope that the theory can be quantized so that virtual gravitons will be involved in the interactions.

Comment: As I said at the time, you should not have been told this. Earth is not sending real particles. But it is *really* sending virtual particles. That's what it means to be a source for a quantized field.