# Virtual photons

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, coulombs-law, virtual-particles, carrier-particles

Is it true what is said about photons that carry electromagnetic force or field? are they virtual photons too? Where exist real photons?
I don't understand the concept of virtual photon, in photoelectric effect we can count the photons, or another example: if we put a dielectric around an electric charge the electrostatic field decreases, so is it not necessary to exist real particles?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142159/50583 and its linked questions

Comment: maybe my answer here will help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185110/do-virtual-particles-actually-physically-exist/185139#185139  it answers the first sentence. ACURIUS link answers the second mathematically