# Can the Coulomb potential as the vacuum energy shift in QED also be calculated with a field quantized in the Coulomb gauge?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, coulombs-law, virtual-particles, gauge, carrier-particles

[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/185283/102243) explains how the Coulomb-potential can be calculated as the energy shift of the (photon) ground state for 2 charges fixed in place. This calculation has been done for a covariant "quantization" of the electromagnetic field, where one has 2 transverse photon degrees of freedom, and one longitudinal and one temporal one. The book by Cohen-Tanoudji ("Atom-Photon Interaction") explains this quantization in detail, and also points out what the coulomb potential amounts to in this way of describing things.

Now I wonder - Can the same calculation also be carried out when on has quantized the electromagnetic field in the Coulomb-gauge, in the way it is usualy done in lectures on quantum optics?

I tried calculating:
\begin{align}
\hat{H}_{int} = 2 \hat{\vec{p}}_1 \hat{\vec{A}}(\hat{\vec{x}}_1) +  \hat{\vec{p}}_2\hat{\vec{A}}(\hat{\vec{x}}_2)
\Delta E = \langle 0 | \hat{H}_{int} | 0 \rangle + \sum_n \frac{ \langle 0 | \hat{H}_{int} |  n \rangle  \langle n | \hat{H}_{int} |  n \rangle }{-E_n}
\end{align}
With $\hat{\vec{A}}$ being replaced by the expansion in creation and annihilation operators, but because the $\hat{\vec{p}}_i$ become $k_i$ in the nominator instead of the denominator,the result differs from the linked answer.

I suspect that the answer is no, because when quantizing the electromagnetic field in the Coulomb-gauge, one implicitly "quantizes" only the transverse degrees of freedom, and set's the $A_0$ component of the 4-potential to 0.

What is the best way to see this?